# trying to use kafka-node with angular6 gives a zlib_bindings not found issue

Tags: node.js, angular, apache-kafka, buffer, zlib

I am trying to use `kafka-node` npm package in an Angular-6 app. 
As part of the initial `kafka-node` npm package installation i have installed `zlib` since it was showing as a dependency. 
As part of running the application using `ng serve`, it gives the following error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in '*[local path removed]*\angkfkapp\node_modules\zlib\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*[local path removed ]*\angkfkapp\node_modules\node-zookeeper-client\lib\jute'
ERROR in ./node_modules/buffermaker/test/BufferMaker.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'should' in '*[local path removed ]*\angkfkapp\node_modules\buffermaker\test'
```

Comment: Are you sure that the library will work in the browser? Bear in mind, Angular is not executed by Node, it's executed by the browser

Comment: I am not sure ,i have send data captured from my angular app to a kafka eco system. for which i found that kafa-node is a popular package used which i am trying to integrate through angular, if needed i can expose kafa-node as a back-end node service to the angular-app

Comment: Okay, you can try taking a look at some of the comments over at [this GitHub page](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/322#issuecomment-394324380)

Comment: @user184994 this solves the zlib issue , however i still get below issue `ERROR in ./node_modules/buffermaker/test/BufferMaker.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'should' in '[local path removed]\angkfkapp\node_modules\buffermaker\test'
i`

Comment: Sounds like you need to install add that to your dev dependencies `npm i should --save-dev`

Comment: Did this fix , now ng serve is fine, however at runtime it gives a different error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.inherits (inherits_browser.js:5)
    at Object../node_modules/kafka-node/lib/wrapper/BrokerReadable.js (BrokerReadable.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/kafka-node/lib/wrapper/BrokerWrapper.js (BrokerWrapper.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js (client.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object.`